# Polynomial class

Tags: c++, mathematics

I'm looking for some assistance on an exercise for my C++ programming class. Unfortunately, I was rather ill the previous week an was unable to attend class, meaning I have only been able to use the textbook as a resource. I have done my best to complete the exercises, but, both because of my absence in class and my beginner status, I feel the code is rather flawed. I would really appreciate any corrections and suggestions, even moreso if you can elaborate on them.

Here are the instructions we were given for the assignment:

> This assignment deals with representing and manipulating polynomials
>   using simple arrays. A polynomial, such as anxn + an-1xn-1 + … + a0,
>   will be implemented as an array of coefficients, with coefficient ai
>   being stored in location i of the array. The coefficients are floating
>   point values (potentially negative), so we will use an array of type
>   double. The array will be dynamically allocated. This will allow us to
>   represent very large polynomials and also allow us to increase the
>   size of the array during execution if necessary.
>
> The file **Poly.h** describes all the functions provided by the class.
>
> You are to implement the following set of functions:
>
> - Default constructor that dynamically allocates an array of `DEFAULTPOLY` elements (set to 50) and constructs a polynomial value of
>     0.
> - A specialized (or alternate) constructor that takes an argument which indicates the size of the desired dynamic array and constructs a
>     zero polynomial
> - A copy constructor
> - A destructor
> - An assignment operator
> - `maxSize`, which tells us the size of the currently allocated dynamic array
> - `grow`, to allocate a new, larger dynamic array and fill it with the existing data
> - `setCoeff`, to set a specific coefficient in the polynomial
> - `retrieveCoeff* to get a specific coefficient from the polynomial
> - *incrementCoeff`, to add a value to a specific coefficient in the polynomial
> - `degree`, which determines the degree of the polynomial
> - `numOfTerms`, which determines the number of terms in the polynomial (i.e., how many array elements are nonzero)
> - `evaluate`, which evaluates the polynomial for a given value of X
> - `add`, which adds one polynomial to another, changing the polynomial added to, growing the dynamic array if necessary
> - `subtract`, which subtracts one polynomial from another, changing the polynomial subtracted from, growing the dynamic array if
>     necessary
> - `derivative`, which computes the derivative of a polynomial
> - `equals`, which determines the equality of two polynomials
> - `negate, which negates a polynomial
> - `multByConst`, which multiplies a polynomial by a constant value
>
> Several functions are provided for you:
>
> 1. A `toString()` function will be provided to you so that >all our polynomials will be displayed identically.
> 2. The insertion operator is defined so we can easily print a polynomial
> 3. The equality, inequality, and addition operators are provided and are simply defined in terms of your equals and add functions. You should not change any of the provided functions.
>
> You will be supplied with one **Poly.h** file. The class declaration
>   file Poly.h contains a complete specification of a class named Poly.
>   Your task will be create the file Poly.cpp and to implement all the
>   specified functions. Then you will need to create a PolyTest.cpp
>   program to test your ADT.

Below is the the .h file we were provided with:

> ```
> #ifndef POLY_H
> #define POLY_H
>
> #include <string>
> using namespace std;
>
>
> // default size of our dynamic coefficient array
> const size_t DEFAULTPOLY = 50;    
>
> class Poly
> {
>
> private:
>
>   // Data members   [implementation of ADT's data object]
>   // Feel free to change to meet your needs.
>
>   size_t maxPoly;    // size of array
>   double *coeff;     // dynamic array
>
>
>
> public:
>
>   // Default Class constructor
>   // Allocate an array of DEFAULTPOLY elements and initializes it to the constant 0
>   // post: Class object is initialized to degree-0 polynomial of 0  
>   Poly ();
>
>   // Non-default (alternate) Class constructor
>   // Allocate an array of 'size' elements and initializes it to the constant 0
>   // post: Class object is initialized to degree-0 polynomial of 0  
>   Poly (size_t size);
>
>   // Copy constructor
>   // Construct a new Poly that is a copy of an existing Poly
>   // post: Class object is initialized to be a copy of the argument Poly
>   Poly (const Poly& aPoly);
>
>   // Destructor
>   // Destroy a poly object by freeing the dynamically allocated array
>   ~Poly ();
>
>   // Assignment operator
>   // Assign rhs Poly object to 'this' Poly object
>   const Poly& operator= (const Poly& rhs);
>
>
>
>   // Member functions   [specs for ADT's operations]
>
>   // maxSize
>   // Return the size of the coefficient array
>   size_t maxSize() const;
>
>
>   // grow
>   // This method will allow us to increase the size of the dynamically allocated
>   // array by allocating a new array of the desired size, copying the data from
>   // the old array to the new array, and then releasing the old array.
>   // If the newSize is less than or equal to the current size, then no actions 
>   // are taken.
>   // Note: the maximum degree of a polynomial is one less than the size of the 
>   // array. The parameter newSize represents the size of the array.
>   void grow (size_t newSize);
>
>
>   // degree
>   // Finds the degree of a polynomial (the highest power with a
>   //    non-zero coefficient)
>   // pre: Class object exists
>   // post: Returns the degree of the polynomial object.
>   size_t degree () const;
>
>   // setCoeff
>   // Sets a term, value*x^i, in a polynomial, growing the array if necessary.
>   // pre: Class object has been initialized. 0 <= i.
>   // post: In the polynomial, the term with power i has coefficient
>   //       value. The polynomical was grown if required.
>   // Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
>   void setCoeff (double value, size_t i);
>
>   // retrieveCoeff
>   // Finds the coefficient of the x^i term in poly
>   // pre: Class object has been initialized. 0 <= i
>   // post: Returns the value of the coefficient of the term with power i
>   // note: If the object does not contain a term with power i (e.g., 
>   //       i>=maxPoly), a coefficient value of zero is returned.
>   // Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
>   double retrieveCoeff (size_t i) const;
>
>   // incrementCoeff
>   // Changes a term, value*x^i, in a polynomial, growing the polynomial if required.
>   // pre: Class object has been initialized. 0 <= i.
>   // post: In the Class object the term with power i has its coefficient
>   //       incremented by the given value. The array has grown if necessary.
>   // Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
>   void incrementCoeff (double value, size_t i);
>
>   // toString  
>   // Produce a string representation of a Poly object
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized.
>   // post: A string representation is returned.
>   // dependencies: This function requires that the degree() and 
>   //  retrieveCoeff() functions are implemented.
>   // note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
>   string toString () const;
>
>   // numOfTerms
>   // Returns the number of terms in the polynomial.
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized.
>   // post: The number of non-zero terms of the polynomial is returned.
>   size_t numOfTerms () const;
>
>   // evaluate
>   // Evaluate a polynomial for a specified value of X
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized
>   // post: The polynomial will be evaluated for the value of
>   //       X received as an argument. The resulting value is
>   //       returned.
>   double evaluate (double x) const;
>
>   // add
>   // Add one polynomial to another
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
>   //       argument is also an initialized poly object.
>   // post: The argument polynomial is added to the object polynomial.
>   //       The object polynomial is changed to hold the sum. The object
>   //       polynomial is grown if required to hold the resulting sum.
>   // Note: the poly object being operated upon may be of a different
>   //   size (maxPoly) than the aPoly parameter. If the aPoly parameter
>   //   has a degree larger than the array in the 'this' Poly object,
>   //   then the array is grown large enough to hold the sum.
>   void add (const Poly& aPoly);
>
>   // subtract
>   // Subtract one polynomial from another
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
>   //       argument is also an initialized poly object.
>   // post: The argument polynomial is subtracted from the object polynomial.
>   //       The object polynomial is changed to hold the result. The object
>   //       polynomial is grown if required to hold the result.
>   // Note: the poly object being operated upon may be of a different
>   //   size (maxPoly) than the aPoly parameter. If the aPoly parameter
>   //   has a degree larger than the array in the 'this' Poly object,
>   //   then the array is grown large enough to hold the result.
>   void subtract (const Poly& aPoly);
>
>   // addition operator
>   // Add two polynomials together and return a new polynomial that is the result
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
>   //       argument is also an initialized poly object.
>   // post: The argument polynomial is added to the object polynomial, and the
>   //       result is stored in a new polynomial which is returned.
>   //       The object polynomial is not changed.
>   // note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
>   Poly operator+ (const Poly& rhs) const;
>
>   // subtraction operator
>   // Subtracts one polynomial from another and return a new polynomial that is the result
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
>   //       argument is also an initialized poly object.
>   // post: The argument polynomial is subtracted from the object polynomial, and the
>   //       result is stored in a new polynomial which is returned.
>   //       The object polynomial is not changed.
>   // note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
>   Poly operator- (const Poly& rhs) const;
>
>   // equals
>   // Determine if two polynomials are equal
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
>   //       argument is also an initialized poly object.
>   // post: Returns true if the two polynomials are equal, false otherwise.
>   bool equals (const Poly& aPoly) const;
>
>   // Equality/inequality operators
>   // note: These functions have been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
>   bool operator== (const Poly& rhs) const;
>   bool operator!= (const Poly& rhs) const;
>
>
>   // negate
>   // Negate a polynomial
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized.
>   // post: The polynomial has been changed to represent its
>   //       multiplication by -1.0.
>   void negate ();
>
>   // multByConst
>   // Multiply a polynomial by a constant
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized.
>   // post: The polynomial has been changed to represent its
>   //       multiplication by the value of argument val.
>   void multByConst (double val);
>
>   // derivative
>   // Compute the derivative of a polynomial
>   // pre: The class object has been initialized.
>   // post: The polynomial has been changed to represent its
>   //       derivative.
>   void derivative ();
>
>
>   // insertion operator for output
>   // note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
>   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Poly &p);
> #endif
> };
> ```

An finally, here is the .cpp file I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include "Poly.h"
using namespace std;


// Default Class constructor
// Allocate an array of DEFAULTPOLY elements and initializes it to the constant 0
// post: Class object is initialized to degree-0 polynomial of 0  
Poly::Poly()
{
    coeff = new double [DEFAULTPOLY];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) DEFAULTPOLY; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] = 0.0;
    }
    maxPoly = DEFAULTPOLY;
}

// Non-default (alternate) Class constructor
// Allocate an array of 'size' elements and initializes it to the constant 0
// post: Class object is initialized to degree-0 polynomial of 0  
Poly::Poly(size_t size)
{
    coeff = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) size; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] = 0.0;
    }
    maxPoly = size;
}

// Copy constructor
// Construct a new Poly that is a copy of an existing Poly
// post: Class object is initialized to be a copy of the argument Poly
Poly::Poly(const Poly& aPoly)
{
    coeff = new double[aPoly.maxPoly];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) aPoly.maxPoly; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] = aPoly.coeff[i];
    }
    maxPoly = aPoly.maxPoly;
}

// Destructor
// Destroy a poly object by freeing the dynamically allocated array
Poly::~Poly()
{
    delete[] coeff;
}

// Assignment operator
// Assign rhs Poly object to 'this' Poly object
const Poly& Poly::operator= (const Poly& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs){
        return *this;
    }
    Poly tmp(rhs);
    std::swap(maxPoly, tmp.maxPoly);
    std::swap(coeff, tmp.coeff);
    return *this;
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Member functions   [specs for ADT's operations]
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

// maxSize
// Return the size of the coefficient array
size_t Poly::maxSize() const
{
    size_t maxSize = maxPoly;
    return maxSize;
}

// grow
// This method will allow us to increase the size of the dynamically allocated
// array by allocating a new array of the desired size, copying the data from
// the old array to the new array, and then releasing the old array.
// If the newSize is less than or equal to the current size, then no actions 
// are taken.
// Note: the maximum degree of a polynomial is one less than the size of the 
// array. The parameter newSize represents the size of the array.
void Poly::grow(size_t newSize)
{
    int arrSize = (int) maxPoly;
    if ((int) newSize > arrSize)
    {
        double* newArrPtr = new double[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
        {
            newArrPtr[i] = coeff[i];
        }
        std::swap(newArrPtr, coeff);
        std::swap(newSize, maxPoly);
    }

}

// degree
// Finds the degree of a polynomial (the highest power with a
//    non-zero coefficient)
// pre: Class object exists
// post: Returns the degree of the polynomial object.
size_t Poly::degree() const
{
    size_t degree = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)maxPoly; i++)
    {
        if (coeff[i] != 0)
        {
            degree = (size_t)i;
        }
    }
    return degree;
}


// setCoeff
// Sets a term, value*x^i, in a polynomial, growing the array if necessary.
// pre: Class object has been initialized. 0 <= i.
// post: In the polynomial, the term with power i has coefficient
//       value. The polynomical was grown if required.
// Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
void Poly::setCoeff(double value, size_t i)
{
    if ((size_t)0 <= i && i <= maxPoly)
    {
        if (i > maxPoly)
        {
            grow(i);
        }
        coeff[i] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
}

// retrieveCoeff
// Finds the coefficient of the x^i term in poly
// pre: Class object has been initialized. 0 <= i
// post: Returns the value of the coefficient of the term with power i
// note: If the object does not contain a term with power i (e.g., 
//       i>=maxPoly), a coefficient value of zero is returned.
// Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
double Poly::retrieveCoeff(size_t i) const
{
    if (0 <= (int)i)
    {
        return coeff[i];
    }
    else if (i >= (int)maxPoly)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
}

// incrementCoeff
// Changes a term, value*x^i, in a polynomial, growing the polynomial if required.
// pre: Class object has been initialized. 0 <= i.
// post: In the Class object the term with power i has its coefficient
//       incremented by the given value. The array has grown if necessary.
// Throws <std::out_of_range> if index i does not meet the precondition.
void Poly::incrementCoeff(double value, size_t i)
{
    if (0 <= (int)i)
    {
        if (i > (int)maxPoly)
        {
            grow(i);
        }
        coeff[i] *= value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }

}

// toString  
// Produce a string representation of a Poly object
// pre: The class object has been initialized.
// post: A string representation is returned.
// dependencies: This function requires that the degree() and 
//  retrieveCoeff() functions are implemented.
// note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
string Poly::toString() const
{
    ostringstream result;
    bool printedSomething = false;
    for (int i = (int)degree(); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        double c = retrieveCoeff(i);
        if (c != 0.0)
        {
            printedSomething = true;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                result.setf(ios::showpos);
                result << " " << c;
                result.unsetf(ios::showpos);
            }
            else
            {
                result.setf(ios::showpos);
                result << " " << c;
                result.unsetf(ios::showpos);
                result << "*X^" << i;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!printedSomething)
    {
        result.setf(ios::showpos);
        result << " " << 0;
        result.unsetf(ios::showpos);
    }
    return result.str();

}

// numOfTerms
// Returns the number of terms in the polynomial.
// pre: The class object has been initialized.
// post: The number of non-zero terms of the polynomial is returned.
size_t Poly::numOfTerms() const
{
    size_t numTerms = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)maxPoly; i++)
    {
        if (coeff[i] != 0)
        {
            numTerms++;
        }
    }
    return numTerms;
}

// evaluate
// Evaluate a polynomial for a specified value of X
// pre: The class object has been initialized
// post: The polynomial will be evaluated for the value of
//       X received as an argument. The resulting value is
//       returned.
double Poly::evaluate(double x) const
{
    double polyTotal = 0.0;
    double coeff = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) maxPoly; i++)
    {
        coeff = retrieveCoeff((size_t) i);
        polyTotal += (coeff * pow(x, (double)i));
    }
    return polyTotal;
}

// add
// Add one polynomial to another
// pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
//       argument is also an initialized poly object.
// post: The argument polynomial is added to the object polynomial.
//       The object polynomial is changed to hold the sum. The object
//       polynomial is grown if required to hold the resulting sum.
// Note: the poly object being operated upon may be of a different
//   size (maxPoly) than the aPoly parameter. If the aPoly parameter
//   has a degree larger than the array in the 'this' Poly object,
//   then the array is grown large enough to hold the sum.
void Poly::add(const Poly& aPoly)
{
    if (aPoly.maxPoly > maxPoly)
    {
        grow(aPoly.maxPoly);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)maxPoly; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] += aPoly.coeff[i];
    }
}

// subtract
// Subtract one polynomial from another
// pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
//       argument is also an initialized poly object.
// post: The argument polynomial is subtracted from the object polynomial.
//       The object polynomial is changed to hold the result. The object
//       polynomial is grown if required to hold the result.
// Note: the poly object being operated upon may be of a different
//   size (maxPoly) than the aPoly parameter. If the aPoly parameter
//   has a degree larger than the array in the 'this' Poly object,
//   then the array is grown large enough to hold the result.
void Poly::subtract(const Poly& aPoly)
{
    if (aPoly.maxPoly > maxPoly)
    {
        grow(aPoly.maxPoly);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) maxPoly; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] -= aPoly.coeff[i];
    }
}

// addition operator
// Add two polynomials together and return a new polynomial that is the result
// pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
//       argument is also an initialized poly object.
// post: The argument polynomial is added to the object polynomial, and the
//       result is stored in a new polynomial which is returned.
//       The object polynomial is not changed.
// note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
Poly Poly::operator+ (const Poly& rhs) const
{
    Poly result;
    result.add(*this);
    result.add(rhs);
    return result;
}

// subtraction operator
// Subtracts one polynomial from another and return a new polynomial that is the result
// pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
//       argument is also an initialized poly object.
// post: The argument polynomial is subtracted from the object polynomial, and the
//       result is stored in a new polynomial which is returned.
//       The object polynomial is not changed.
// note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
Poly Poly::operator- (const Poly& rhs) const
{
    Poly result;
    result.subtract(*this);
    result.subtract(rhs);
    return result;
}

// equals
// Determine if two polynomials are equal
// pre: The class object has been initialized. The received
//       argument is also an initialized poly object.
// post: Returns true if the two polynomials are equal, false otherwise.
bool Poly::equals(const Poly& aPoly) const
{
    if (maxPoly != aPoly.maxPoly)
    {
        return(false);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) maxPoly; i++)
    {
        if (aPoly.coeff[i] != coeff[i])
        {
            return(false);
        }
    }
    return(true);
}

// Equality/inequality operators
// note: These functions have been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
bool Poly::operator== (const Poly& rhs) const
{
    return equals(rhs);
}

bool Poly::operator!= (const Poly& rhs) const
{
    return !equals(rhs);
}


// negate
// Negate a polynomial
// pre: The class object has been initialized.
// post: The polynomial has been changed to represent its
//       multiplication by -1.0.
void Poly::negate()
{
    multByConst(-1.0);
}

// multByConst
// Multiply a polynomial by a constant
// pre: The class object has been initialized.
// post: The polynomial has been changed to represent its
//       multiplication by the value of argument val.
void Poly::multByConst(double val)
{
    double* tmpArray = new double[maxPoly];
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)maxPoly; i++)
    {
        tmpArray[i] = retrieveCoeff((size_t)i) * val;
    }
    std::swap(tmpArray, coeff);
}

// derivative
// Compute the derivative of a polynomial
// pre: The class object has been initialized.
// post: The polynomial has been changed to represent its
//       derivative.
void Poly::derivative()
{
    size_t derivArrSize = maxPoly - 1;
    double* derivArrPtr = new double[derivArrSize];
    for (int i = 1; i < (int) maxPoly; i++)
    {
        double coeffOfDeriv = retrieveCoeff((size_t)i) * (double)i;
        i -= 1;
        derivArrPtr[i] = coeffOfDeriv;
    }
    std::swap(derivArrPtr, coeff);
    std::swap(derivArrSize, maxPoly);
}

// insertion operator for output
// note: This function has been provided for you -- DO NOT CHANGE IT!
ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Poly& p)
{
    out << p.toString();
    return out;
}
```

Please let me know what changes and improvements I can make. Additionally, if you have any suggestions for the testing of the `Poly` class, those would also be welcomed.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::vector`?

Comment: @Corbin unfortunately, we have yet to cover that so I don't believe we can use it.

Comment: The code is broken. It doesn't even compile (line 416: `tmpArray.maxPoly` for example). Voting to close.

Comment: @vnp I have now fixed the code so that it complies. As I mentioned in the original post, I am a beginner and, thus, had trouble fixing the errors. You may notice that I acknowledged my .cpp has flaws and that those issues were part of the reason I needed help with review. I have since been reading other stackoverflow posts and have figured out how to fix the errors so that it compiles. However, the code still needs help.

Comment: @Nea If it doesn't compile You need to take it to StackOverflow. Then once you've fixed compilation issues & bugs bring it back here and we will help you in making your code look awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Technically the code is still broken. Few observations anyway.

- In-place modifiers (`multByConstant`, `derivative`) do not need a temporary array. You may modify coefficients directly, same way you do in  `add` and `subtract`.
- C-style casts almost always signal that something is wrong. In your case, using `int` for loop index is a bug: `size_t` may cover a larger span of values than `int`, which means that the `int` index would not be able to reach the whole array when `maxPoly` is large enough. Declare the index to be the same type as loop limits.
- `evaluate` implementation is inefficient and numerically unsound. See [Horner scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for details.
- To increment something one would add, not multiply (`incrementCoeff`)
- `derivative` loop never terminates.